# MySQL Full-Text search starting with short word fails

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I'm using a query like this in PHP to find posts by title and content:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_table` WHERE MATCH(ptitle, pcontent) AGAINST ("+'.$search.'*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It works quite well, but I have trouble when searching starts with a short word like Spanish articles ('el', 'la').

For example, when I'm trying to find a post with the title "El Perro" among other posts, I do the following searches and I get:

- "El Perro" -> nothing.
- "Perro" -> found.
- "El" -> returns other posts but not the one I'm looking for.
- "Perro El Perro" -> found.

Apparently the problem occurs when the search starts with a short word. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Full text there are  minimum  values  for the length of a word

> By default, words less than 3 characters in length or greater than 84
>   characters in length do not appear in an InnoDB full-text search
>   index. Maximum and minimum word length values are configurable using
>   the innodb_ft_max_token_size and innodb_ft_min_token_size variables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

You can change this limit modifing the value in sql.ini

```
 [mysqld]
 ft_min_word_len = 3
```

The default value is 4 and the above will change it to 3. You can change 
  ft_max_word_len in the same manner:

```
 [mysqld]
 ft_max_word_len = 150
```

Comment: But why when searching for the word "el", does it return results? And, is possible to tell him to ignore short words? Because when I search for "el perro", it returns 0 results. The problem only occurs when the search starts with a short word, if the short word is in the middle, it works fine.

Comment: some words are in special list ..  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html   ..  for a complete full text doc exam you should take e deep read for this chapter ..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html